# How can I use hardcoded access key ID & secret key credentials when using the AWS SDK for Rust?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, aws-sdk-rust

In Boto3 I could provide the access key explicitly:

```py
dynamodb_client = boto3.resource("dynamodb",
                                 region_name=...,
                                 aws_access_key_id=...,
                                 aws_secret_access_key=...)
```

How can I achieve the same in Rust?

I only see a function that reads it from env (`~/.aws/credentials`):

```rust
let shared_config: SdkConfig = aws_config::load_from_env().await;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>*Standard caveat applies: please don't use hardcoded credentials unless absolutely necessary - it isn't secure.*</sup>

Use the [`aws-credential-types`](https://docs.rs/aws-credential-types/1.1.1/aws_credential_types/) dependency with the [`hardcoded-credentials`](https://docs.rs/crate/aws-credential-types/1.1.1/features#hardcoded-credentials) feature enabled. This will allow you to use the [`Credentials::from_keys`](https://docs.rs/crate/aws-credential-types/1.1.1/source/src/credentials_impl.rs) method:

> /// Creates `Credentials` from hardcoded access key, secret key, and session token.

```rust
use aws_credential_types::Credentials;

// ...

let access_key_id = "xxx";
let secret_access_key = "yyy";

let credentials = Credentials::from_keys(access_key_id, secret_access_key, None);
```

---

Here is a complete yet minimal working Rust CLI app to demonstrate the above:

```rust
// cargo.toml

[package]
name = "aws-sdk-for-rust-hardcoded-credentials-demo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
aws-credential-types = { version = "1.1.1", features = ["hardcoded-credentials"] }
aws-types = "1.1.1"
aws-sdk-dynamodb = { version = "1.7.0", features = ["behavior-version-latest"] }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }

// main.rs

use aws_credential_types::Credentials;
use aws_sdk_dynamodb::Config;
use aws_types::region::Region;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let access_key_id = "xxx";
    let secret_access_key = "yyy";

    let credentials = Credentials::from_keys(access_key_id, secret_access_key, None);

    let config = Config::builder()
        .credentials_provider(credentials)
        .region(Region::new("eu-west-1"))
        .build();

    let dynamodb_client = aws_sdk_dynamodb::Client::from_conf(config);

    let list_tables_response = dynamodb_client.list_tables().send().await.unwrap();

    if let Some(table_names) = list_tables_response.table_names {
        println!("DynamoDB tables: {:?}", table_names);
    } else {
        println!("No DynamoDB tables");
    }
}
```